# I've set the system locale on Windows 10 to use the beta UTF-8 support, but RStudio does not recognize it

Tags: r, windows, utf-8, windows-10, rstudio

As you can see, I've changed the locale to support UTF-8

[image: I've changed the locale to support UTF-8]

However, when I try to change the locale in RStudio to UTF-8, I get an error:

```
> Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.utf8")
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.utf8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.utf8" cannot be honored
```

I thought that since I enabled UTF-8 support for Windows, that I'd be able to change the locale in RStudio. Is there any way to do it?

Current locale is English_United States.1252:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

Using RStudio build 351, with R version 4.1.0 on Windows 10 Home version 21H1

Comment: Note: `en_US.utf8` is not the notation used by Microsoft. In any case, check https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/07/30/windows/utf-8-build-of-r-and-cran-packages/index.html

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi so even if I use the correct notation, I wouldn't be able to use UTF-8 as the encoding without that demo build of R?

Comment: You can use UTF-8 in R (and in Rstudio), in the old way. Your question is about the Microsoft beta on using UTF-8 as default locale. For this, you need also the beta version of R. But from your comment, it seems you just want just to use UTF-8 in Rstudio https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding-in-the-RStudio-IDE [Note: Microsoft is using Unicode since a long time (and all display is done with Unicode). The beta change is subtle: it is about default for "unaware" programs. RStudio and many other apps handle encoding explicitly]

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi it turns out I was making a mistake. I was reading the csv with read.csv(), but changing it to readr's read_csv() fixed it, and read it in the correct encoding. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was in how I was reading the data. Reading it with `read.csv()` read it with the encoding set by the locale. Changing it to `readr::read_csv()` made sure the file was being read with its own encoding, UTF-8.